# Django display list data in json

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am using django to display pandas data frame into json format I am suing django panda I can convert my model into data frame but I don't know how to display whole frame in json format.  I am using this code:

```
def index(request):
qs = DebtManagement1S.objects.all()
df = qs.to_dataframe()
resp_data = {
    'x': list(df['sector']),
    'z': df.to_json()
    }
return JsonResponse(resp_data)
```

And it is returning [Json response](https://gist.github.com/nwoow/3b614abfd4b6b149da0373e2c3d15dc7)  In my x value I can get a result in list but when I am doing df.to_json() it is returning value in string and I can't use it as a reponse. I want to return a proper json response where I can access it. Is there any way to convert it into json format and return values like this:

```
 {
   sector: {
            "Internal Debt",
             "Central Loans"
         ...
           }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `resp_data` dict needs to consist of Python data structures. So you should call `df.to_dict()`.

Comment: I am new to django can you please explain this.

Comment: Er, explain what? This has nothing to do with Django.